# Is possible to run ASP.NET MVC 1 with .NET 2.0.50727?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a site with ASP.NET MVC 1, and now I'm trying to deploy it to a server with .net 2.0.50727. Since it is not working, I started to think that the main error is that the server doesn't support MVC 1.

Am I right? In other words, can I run ASP.NET MVC in a server with .NET 2.0.50727?

Comment: Important: even though .NET 3.5 SP1 installed the ASP.NET runtime version reported in IIS is .NET 2.0.50727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work out-of-the-box, MVC 1 is designed to work with .Net 3.5 Framework.

This doesn't mean it can't be done. Check out this post from Scott Hanselman: 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx

This is what he had to do to get it working:

- Developed on Visual Studio 2008
- Targeted .NET 2.0 in Project Properties
- Deployed the Application to a .NET 2.0 SP1 machine
- Copied System.Core.dll local to the web apps /bin folder

I looked into this not too long ago but never got it working. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC 1.0 requires .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1.

> System Requirements Supported
>   Operating Systems: Windows Server
>   2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows
>   Vista; Windows XP 
>   .NET 3.5 SP1.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en

Comment: it can be done, as Brian says, but is strongly not recommended